# If $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ how do I find an example where $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ also is open?

Tags: summation

If $(A_n)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
How can I find an example where $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ also is open?

I'm new to this concept, so any leads would be much appreciated!

Comment: If all $A_n$ are the same, for example... Much more interesting question is, when the intersection is NOT open.

Comment: Or when they are disjoint like $A_n=(n,n+1)$.

Comment: Or when $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3\subseteq \ldots$ (more generalized than sranthrop's example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some classical examples:

1. Open
   $$A_n:=(0,1)^2\rightarrow\bigcap A_n=(0,1)^2$$
2. Closed

$$A_n:=(0-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})^2\rightarrow\bigcap A_n=[0,1]^2$$

3. Not closed nor open

$$A_n:=(0-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n})\times(0,1)\rightarrow\bigcap A_n=[0,1]\times (0,1)$$

4. Clopen (closed and open) [Joke!]

$$A_n:=\emptyset\rightarrow \bigcap A_n=\emptyset$$